# Using ngx-intl-tel-input break Mat Dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog, mat

If I use ngx-tel-input it renders an empty dialog.

```
 <ngx-intl-tel-input name="phone" formControlName="PhoneNumber"
                        [cssClass]="{'form-control h-auto form-control-solid py-4 d-block': 1 }"
                        [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries" [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true"
                        [enablePlaceholder]="true" [searchCountryFlag]="true"
                        [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2, SearchCountryField.Name]"
                        [selectFirstCountry]="true" [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.UnitedStates" [maxLength]="15"
                        [phoneValidation]="true" [separateDialCode]="separateDialCode"
                        [numberFormat]="PhoneNumberFormat.National">
 </ngx-intl-tel-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be rest of the html code around the `ngx-intl-tel-input`, check for differences what might be missing. I don't see anything explicitly wrong with the code you have provided.

```html
  <form #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="phoneForm">
    <ngx-intl-tel-input 
    [cssClass]="'custom'" 
    [preferredCountries]="['sg']" 
    [onlyCountries]="['my', 'us']"
    [enablePlaceholder]="true"
    [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true"
    name="phone" 
    formControlName="phone"></ngx-intl-tel-input>
  </form>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

    phoneForm = new FormGroup({
        phone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    });

}
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-intl-tel-input-cxfoib?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html